# sessions with twisted.web

Tags: python, twisted.web

I want to store a instance of ldap connection in a session var. I use request.getSession() but don't work correctly. My code:

```
session = request.getSession()

connect = LdapConnection(request.args['host'][0],'cn='+request.args['user'][0]+',ou=People,dc=Company',request.args['password'][0])

session.addComponent(LdapConnection,connect)
```

When I need the instance of ldapconnection, I want to recover but don't work :(

```
conect = session.getComponent(LdapConnection)
```

Comment: "Doesn't work." What happens? Nothing? A stack trace?

Comment: Does nothing, it doesn't store the instance of the connection

Comment: possible duplicate of [Store an instance of a connection - twisted.web](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4936994/store-an-instance-of-a-connection-twisted-web)